# "allow the shortcut key to start sticky keys" option keeps getting ticked back on

Tags: keyboard

I'm trying to permanently disable Sticky Keys. Something is not working.

Here's what the Sticky Keys option in the Settings menu looks like:

[image]

Here's what the Sticky Keys option in the Control Panel/Ease of Access looks like:

[image]

Yet whenever I press Shift rapidly, the option will TURN ITSELF BACK ON.

[image]

This is driving me nuts. How do I permanently disable sticky keys?  Is there a registry entry where  I can purge it once and for all?  Why does this option keep turning itself back on.

Comment: Use `regedit` to navigate to the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\StickyKeys`. If the item `Flags` is not `506`, set it to this value and reboot. If this doesn't help, try to rename the key `StickyKeys` and reboot again.

Comment: You might also need in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility` to set the item `Configuration` to empty.